# Is there a code to hide empty rows on multiple columns?

Tags: vba, hide

I am looking for a code to hide empty rows for a specific range of columns by using a toggle button.  I have a table starting in P9 to U71 and I would like a code to hide any row that does not contain any data in that specific table.  I have tried several codes with the most recent posted below but this code is hiding based on the values in column U and even if there was data in that same row but in a different column.  I should note that I have zero experience with coding and thus I thank you for any assistance with this issue.

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
Set r = Range("q9:u71")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In r
      If Len(c.Text) = 0 Then
              c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
      Else
              c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
      End If
 Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So, would you like to hide all the rows in the specified range, **if there are completely empty**. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunction.CountA` on each row. If the result is 0, hide the row.

Comment: Then, check the adapted code I posted. But if cells in the processed range are modified by code and some (already) hidden cells receive a value, don't you need those rows to be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 Dim i As Long, rngH As Range

 For i = 9 To 71
      If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("P" & i & ":U" & i)) = 0 Then
              If rngH Is Nothing Then
                   Set rngH = Range("P" & i)
              Else
                   Set rngH = Union(rngH, Range("P" & i))
              End If
      End If
 Next i
 If Not rngH Is Nothing Then rngH.EntireRow.Select '.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

It only selects the rows to be hidden. If it works as you need, put `.Hidden = True` instead of `Select`.

It should be very fast, placing the empty cells in a range and hiding the `EntireRow`at once, at the end.

Now, if the cells in the processed range are modified by code and some (already) hidden cells receive a value, don't you need to make them visible?

I will close my laptop. If the answer to my above question is yes, please use the next code. If not, do not use it...

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 Dim r As Range, i As Long, rngH As Range, rngV As Range

 For i = 9 To 71
      If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("P" & i & ":U" & i)) = 0 Then
              If rngH Is Nothing Then
                   Set rngH = Range("P" & i)
              Else
                   Set rngH = Union(rngH, Range("P" & i))
              End If
      Else
             If rngV Is Nothing Then
                   Set rngV = Range("P" & i)
              Else
                   Set rngV = Union(rngV, Range("P" & i))
              End If
      End If
 Next i
 If Not rngH Is Nothing Then rngH.EntireRow.Hidden = True
 If Not rngV Is Nothing Then rngV.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried both codes but none worked.  When I clicked "Run Sub/User Form" nothing happend.

Comment: What to be clcked? You must copy the code (only one) in the sheet module and it will automatically run whwn sheet is activated. This is a sheet event!

Comment: Ah, I see.  I am actually using a toggle button... as I mentioned, I have zero knowledge in VBA so I apologize as I stumble.

Comment: @Karla: Now, when you have some knowledge, can you send some feedback about your tests? If you had a problem, please explain it. If not, it is at least polite to send some feedback...

Comment: @Karla: I used your sample code like it was. I can simple adapt it to work like a Sub, when you need running it... But you must say what you need and send some feedback.

Comment: Here's what I am attempting to do and have failed.  I created a toggle button that I would like to link to a code so that when I press it, it hides empty rows in columns P-U.  I will eventually attempt to create a separate button that will unhide such rows when pressed.

Comment: @Karla: Please, modify the Sub name in `Sub Worksheet_ActivateXX()`, copy it in any standard module and run the code. After copying (being in VBE Visual Basic Editor, press F5). The code will run and do what you need. Use first code which will only select the empty rows of the range P:U. Take only care if the sheet you need to process is activated...